# Embedded firmware and app?

Tags: arduino, embedded, hardware, firmware

I am in Hardware Design trying to get into Embedded Systems, so please pardon me for lame questions.

So,

Scenario 1 : I upload an Arduino Sketch into Arduino with the help of Arduino Bootloader .

Scenario 2 : I develop a PCB on which first firmware is flashed and then a Linux based app is installed.

**Questions :**

**1. Can Arduino Bootloader be called as the firmware?**

**2. Can Arduino Sketch be equated to an app?**

**3. What language is the bootloader programmed in? Is it C?**

**4. What is the common programming language for firmware?**

**5. Do Embedded Systems Engineers need to learn app development (Linux /Android /whatever) too?
Or just efficiency in the firmware part(C** I guess) **is enough?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Skills such as debugging and how to program apply to any language. Eg. You could be proficient in C, but a poor programmer. Net result is your code is poorly structured but valid C. Debugging is a skill that is invaluable regardless of language or hardware. Be it fixing a car, troubleshooting a pcb or finding a bug in code, the techniques are much the same. Just about everything else you’ll pick up on the job.

Comment: @Kartman, thanks, you exactly got my point which is Debugging. I would like to contribute to debugging even if the bug is not in the hardware instead of calling the software team, when my designed product (PCB) has a bug. That firmware problem, which I would like to address, for that I am asking how to start. If it's a problem in the application, definitely software team will be handling that but hardware debugging (firmware part), I would like to know more about. eg. JTAG etc. Arduino is too easy, I know C and it's sketches don't look like firmware to me.

Comment: Arduino too easy?  Definitely Arduino gives you a known starting point but still the skill is in writing code. They give you a core library for the basics which you can choose to use or not. If not, you end up writing much the same anyway. Also note that Arduino is C++ - there’s no special magic. If you go to platformio you get debugging features. From  $5 usd upwards you can get dev boards with integrated debug and with Arduino support so the cost of entry is low.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I usually refer to the entire software on a small MCU as firmware. So in this case, the combination of bootloader and application is the firmware.
2. Sure.
3. The [Arduino bootloader](https://docs.arduino.cc/hacking/software/Bootloader#source-code) is indeed written in C.
4. There are more than one common language. But C is the most common.
5. Depends on what you want to work with. In a small team, developing some Linux based hardware, it is likely that you will also get involved in writing apps for said hardware.

Answer (score 1):

The answers may be opinion based, there might not be one correct answer, so here's mine for comparison.

1. Depends on who you ask. I'd say no, because bootloader itself is used to load the firmware, so bootloader itself is not the whole firmware, it's just a part of the firmware. Sometimes your MCU will contain a non-erasable factory bootloader so at least that can't be claimed as part of your firmware.
2. No, not really. It might be called application code to separate it from the bootloader code, but it is not an app, in the sense that it is a fixed program, while your PC and phone can just run any app you have installed and switch between them. An embedded system does not compare with a more general purpose computing device capable of running any general purpose apps.
3. There are multiple devices you can call Arduinos, not just a single Arduino. The different Arduino platforms use different MCU families and it would be a huge job to search if each and all bootloaders for all Arduino platforms are made in C or has any of them made with some other language, such as Ada or assembly.
4. It again depends who you ask and what you consider embedded. Embedded linux programs might be written in Python or some C++ framework like Qt. Some firmwares need to be extremely small so they are written in assembly. Some market segments of software such as military or medical might require the software to be written in Ada. There is no one most common given your huge range of scope of just being embedded.
5. Again it depends on the definition of embedded. Writing huge embedded linux programs is not same as writing embedded firmware for a small microcontroller. And it depends on your project and team. Sometimes you must write embedded assembly code for a microcontroller device and then you might need to write a web page, mobile app, C# program or Python script to control your embedded device.

Comment: Although you have fully answered my question, but if it's not too much to ask, could you please share some insight on the comment to my question, which was the actual intent of the question in the first place.